# Shell script: MySQL command inside a container

Tags: mysql, docker, shell

I am trying to automate some tasks utilizing shell. I'm getting trouble when I try to run a MySQL command inside a container.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "Username : " WEBUSER
read -p "User password : " USERPASSWD
read -p "Database name : " DBNAME
 
RTPASSWD=`docker exec -it $(docker ps -f name=mysql -q) cat /run/secrets/password`

docker exec -it $(docker ps -f name=mysql -q) mysql -u root -p${RTPASSWD} -Bse " CREATE USER '${WEBUSER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${USERPASSWD}' ; CREATE DATABASE ${DBNAME}; GRANT ALL ON ${DBNAME}.* TO '${WEBUSER}'@'%' "
```

When I run the script I get the MySQL man. I think it doesn't recognize the MySQL commands because of the ('), but now I don't know how to do it.

```
MySQL  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysql mariadb-client client client-server client-mariadb
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults          Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults             Don't read default options from any option file.
The following specify which files/extra groups are read (specified before remaining options):
--defaults-file=#         Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=#   Read this file after the global files are read.
--defaults-group-suffix=# Additionally read default groups with # appended as a suffix.
.
.
.
```

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: Can you just run `mysql` on the host, connecting to the `docker run -p` port of the container, without running any of these `docker` commands?

Comment: @DavidMaze I cant do this because I'm using it in swarm mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the bash -x I saw the $RTPASSWD with an \r at the end. So, I used sed to remove and it works now. The correction is below:

```
RTPASWD=`docker exec -t $(docker ps -f name=webapp_mysql -q) cat /run/secrets/Maria_root_pwd | sed 's/\r//g'`
```

Thanks!